# How do I wire an ebay AC-DC 12v Power Supply Buck Converter Step Down Module

Tags: buck

I go a few of these from ebay, but they lacked any kind of instructions and it's not obvious from looking at the circuit-board markings which is the input and output

(I guess maybe the holes marked + & - are the DC output, but what is the hole between them?)
[image]

[image]

Edit: added pic of input? side;

[image]

Comment: Undocumented equipment from random eBay sellers, meant to take mains voltage = please be careful about using it to power anything any living thing could touch.

Comment: I am guessing the two outside holes are the outputs also. The middle hole is for a second voltage if a linear regulator is installed on that empty spot on the bottom side. By the way, this is almost for certain a flyback not a buck.

Comment: @rioraxe what's the diff?

Comment: @Ken, when isolation is necessary, flyback is simpler than buck.

Comment: Questions about undocumented equipment from eBay sellers should be posted to eBay sellers.  EE.SE isn't their volunteer application support.

Answer (score 2):

It's sort of hard to tell from your pictures - you really should have also have shown the top side of the board but from the other end.

But it looks as if the end of the board with 3 empty holes is the DC output.  Ignore the middle hole and connect to the two holes marked (+) and (-).

The two holes at the other end of the board look like the input connections.

[Edit]

Yep: it looks as if the two holes marked "J1" are the input power connections.

You should be safe in applying power and testing the supply.

FWIW - this power supply looks to be semi-competent.  Decent clearance between the input and output sections.

The only thing that I don't like is that it looks as if the input rectifier is only half-wave.  I see only a single diode under the input filter cap (D1).  Means this power supply is going to have poor Power Factor.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: added other end pic